# Does Firestore write count increase when I perform the operation with the same existing data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Data in Firestore: [image]

Now suppose if I perform a write operation without updating any data, will it increment the write count in Firestore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran a quick test writing the same value to the same document at an interval, and the usage panel in the Firebase console showed an increase in writes for each write call.